# Fantasy novel series with male protagonist, alternate world, winning hand in marriage, starting a magic school

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, young-adult

I probably read this series through Kindle Unlimited.

A young man wakes up and discovers that he is in an alternative world with magic. He also has magic powers himself. Fairly soon, he arrives at a town where he enters and wins a contest/tournament (either archery or throwing knives, I can’t recall), and is given land, money, the King's daughter's hand in marriage (total wish-fulfillment, I know).

The land in question is under attack by miscellaneous monsters. Eventually he marries the daughter and her two sisters, and they start a school to teach magic (exclusively to women). He constantly denies that it is a harem.

Eventually, he annoys the king and goes on a homesteading trip.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! I hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: "(total wish-fulfillment, I know)." That is definitely some Maury-Sue storyline. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are looking for the book "[Another Typical Day](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22494646-another-typical-day)" by Daniel Harris, the first of the "The Wizards of Eredwynn" series. Which has the spin-off "Generations of Eredwynn" series.

I think that all the points are present in the book, or if not then in the sequels.

David Stephenson suddenly finds himself in a world where the magic spells of an RPG work. He cheats in a shooting competition and wins the eldest daughter of the king, but for all practical purposes gets all 3 of them. He starts to teach magic and is then stripped of his possessions due to a disagreement with the king. So he, his family, and his students leave the kingdom. Still, he does end up with a harem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right. Thank you.